# Null check and listeners in java

Tags: java, android

Very often I see code like this:

```
Listener mListener;

public void setListener(Listener listener){
   mListener=listener;
}

public void fooFunction(){
   ...
   ...
   if (mListener!=null){
      mListener.notifyFoo();
   }
}
```

My question is: what if between the null check and the notifyFoo() another thread calls setListener(null)? Is that possible? or does the compiler make it atomical

Comment: synchronized both the methods so that one thread at a time can execute method. this locking is known as method level lock, if one thread takes a lock other wiat till first complete its execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can synchronize methods

```
public synchronized void setListener(Listener listener){
   mListener=listener;
}

public synchronized void fooFunction(){
   ...
   ...
   if (mListener!=null){
       mListener.notifyFoo();
   }
}
```

Or if you want better granularity of locks

```
private Object monitor = new Object();

public void setListener(Listener listener){
   synchronized (monitor) {
       mListener=listener;
   }
}

public void fooFunction(){
   ...
   ...
   synchronized (monitor) {
        if (mListener!=null){
           mListener.notifyFoo();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the better granularity.  All that needs to be protected is reads from `mListener`.  Synchronising the method is overkill as it will cause contention with other methods that might be synchronised.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that by making your block Synchronized

```
public synchronized void setListener(Listener listener) {
    ....
}

public synchronized void fooFunction() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: ... and the `setListener` method!

Comment: Synchronized both the method. if only this method is synchronized then might be possible that any another thread call setListener method so again fall in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't make anything atomic by default. True, there is a chance of the listener being set to `null` between the two lines. You may use `synchronized` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible. Mark your fooFunction and setListener as synchronized and it should make this code multithread-safe

Comment: That's not enough, `setListener` also needs to be have the `synchronized` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronisation is overkill here.  Just take a copy of the member variable before checking it for `null`:

```
Listener mListener;

public void setListener(Listener listener){
   mListener=listener;
}

public void fooFunction(){
   ...
   ...
   Listener listener = mListener;
   if (listener!=null){
      listener.notifyFoo();
   }
}
```